# student discounts with student ID made from paper

Tags: budget, identity-cards

I am a full-time enrolled student at a German university and will visit London in early March 2020. Unfortunately our student cards are made from paper (with some security features imprinted), exhibiting all typical information given by an EEA ID card, but lacking a picture of the holder. In fact they are only valid when being used with an EEA ID card/ passport, which I will of course carry along.

Do I have a chance TfL and some (non-free) museums will accept this rather unusual concept to apply student discounts or should I get an internationally accepted student card?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you almost certainly aren't eligible for the [standard TfL student discount promotion](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/free-and-discounted-travel/18-plus-student-oyster-photocard?intcmp=54727), since it requires a) you live in London during term time and b) your University is pre-registered with TfL. It's just possible that you could benefit from the [16-25 railcard](https://www.16-25railcard.co.uk) though (which is also available to mature students if you are outside that age bracket).

Museums generally make up their own rules, and it may come down a combination of the person taking your money and your own ability to sell the idea. It's certainly fairly likely that many institutions will be willing to accept it (thus getting some of your money) rather than having you not go in.

Comment: *It's just possible that you could benefit from the 16-25 railcard though (which is also available to mature students if you are outside that age bracket).* Think you would need to take a lot of trips in London to make back the £30. But if any other rail travel in the UK is planned, it would potentially be economical.

Comment: I suspect it's more hassle than it's worth to get a "16-25 railcard", IIRC to get the railcard as a mature student you have to first obtain a paper form, then fill it out and get your university to stamp it.

Comment: Even if OP is older than 16-25 which is the limit for said railcard. Instead of making a mature student application (which I would believe only applies for UK universities) it's much easier to apply for the [26-30 digital railcard](https://www.26-30railcard.co.uk).

Comment: If OP is above that age (31 or older), I would simply advise using a contactless card (if the bank doesn't charge foreign transaction fees) to take the advantage of weekly caps - £36.10 for Zone 1&2.